# two residence permit cards at the same time for non EU

Tags: europe

I am PhD student in Italy. I am visiting researcher in Spain. I have to stay in spain to work on my thesis for one year.
I have renewed my permit of stay in Italy and in Spain I have asked permit card.
There is a problem now. I am not ERASMUS student.  I am non-EU student in Italy and can have just one permit of stay card. I cannot cancel Italian one because I will come back to finish my degree and, I cannot cancel Spanish one because I can stay here up to 90 days with Italian permit of stay card. Now I have two questions:
1.     What is the solution not to have 2 permit cards (that is illegal) and can stay in Spain for one year?
2.     Can I cancel my Spanish stay card and travel to Italy every 90 days? (actually, stay in Spain with Italian permit of stay card and each 90 days go some days to Italy and again go back to Spain)

Comment: I suppose the simplest solution will be to cancel your Italian card and then reapply when you need to move back to Italy.  But where do you see that having two cards is illegal?  There are certainly situations in which it would be required, for example, for a cross-border worker who is a third-country national.  Leaving Spain every 90 days will not work because the limit is 90 days in every 180-day period.  If you stay for 90 days under that rule, you cannot return until you've been away for 90 days.

Comment: If I want to reapply my italian, I have to come back my country and start from begininning. Also, I lost 3 years that it could be useful when I want to change my temporary card to permanent.

Comment: I am sure, it is illegal. I found in immigration principles of Italy and Spain.

Comment: Did you have to go to your country to apply for the Spanish one?  Why would you not be able to apply for the Italian one from Spain?  Can you link to your source for the immigration principles of Spain and/or Italy so we can understand your question better?

Comment: Three years ago I applied for italian visa from my country. Now it is impossible and most of the requests are rejected. I dont know exactly, I would be able to pply italian visa from spain or change spanish permit to italian one. I dont know the source. I sent an email for immigration office and then they said, it is illegal. but when I asked them what is the solution, they didnt answer!